# Как правильно сверстать адаптивно?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Нужно адаптивно сверстать вот такую секцию, используя сетку бутстрапа. 
Скажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить? Задать абсолютно вместе с синим фоном или как...?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это 2 разные картинки, они просто расположены рядом а синий фон их закрывает. Думал задать синий фон контенту col-md, но при зуме фон уезжает и видно "склейку" двух фото.

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?

Comment: народная мудрость гласит: "не пытайтесь впихнуть невпихуемое". Сетка бутстрапа это просто удобный инструмент и если она не подходит, то просто не используйте её для данного элемента страницы, либо рисуйте дизайн, который будет подходить полностью. Если вы всё таки сделаете этот элемент впихнув в сетку бутстрапа, то это всё равно уже будет не сетка бутстрапа :)

Comment: Я не собирался впихивать это в сетку. Это должно быть на секции, в контейнере бутстрапа будет только текст.

Comment: а в чем сложность? Покажите свой код

Comment: Добавил код. Сложность в том, что контейнер при разных разрешениях уезжает, а информация должна находиться в синей области.
Я не знаю, как мне правильно задать фон этой секции, одной картинкой или резать на 2, а синюю часть задавать бэкграундом уже тексту...
Фон задаю секции, контейнер находится внутри этой секции.

Comment: для этого блока bootstrap использовать нет необходимости https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7b5c3vpm/

Comment: Под этим синим боком нет изображения, я тоже думал об этом способе. Вы предлагаете просто склеить фон а синий блок сделать бэкграундом тексту ?

Comment: если нет анимации на каждом фоне отдельно, используйте одно фоновое изображение, а для текста отдельный фон

Comment: Анимации то нет, просто при на определенном разрешении будет видна "склейка", так называемая, которая по логике должна быть под синим блоком.

Comment: как понял, так и ответил, вы думаете из вашего вопроса можно понять, какие элементы где находятся? Если вы хотите чтобы вам качественно помогли сделайте 3 вещи:  1) Подробно и простым языком изложите суть задачи; 2) Добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас есть (HTML и CSS); 3) Чётко обозначьте проблемы, с которыми вам нужно помочь. // Проблема ведь не в том, что никто не знает как вам помочь, проблема в том, что никто не может понять, чем вам нужно помочь :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/gt6px8e6/

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Александр, если ответ помог Вам в решении задачи, пожалуйста, отметьте его галкой, расположенной слева, под стрелками голосования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бутстрап помогает менять макет в зависимости от ширины экрана. Если это нужно для вашей задачи.

[image: md, sm, xs]

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/r7o12djw/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.sochi {
  background: #69c;
  color: white;
}
.sochi > div {
  padding: 0;
}
.sochi img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.sochi .about {
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row sochi">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-4">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x300/9c6/cf9/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 about">
      <h2>Бутстрап</h2>
      <p>помогает менять макет в&nbsp;зависимости от&nbsp;ширины экрана</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img src="//placehold.it/750x300/c69/f9c/" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```